# How do I make sure that bash (not tcsh) is used in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, shell

I have a bash script where I use `ssh` to connect to another server and run some commands there. I found some sites that the error (`Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell.`) is a friendly message but my bash script gets "stuck". No other commands are executed after this message appears. Other forums said to use `ssh -t` to suppress the message but its not working for me. My code looks something like this:

```
.
.
.
stty -echo
sshpass "pwd" ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no usr@1.1.1.1 'su -lc "rm -rf tmp"' 2>/dev/null
stty echo
.
.
.
```

The reason why I'm using `stty-echo` is because I need to switch users to root and the password is displayed on the terminal (which I don't want). I get the error message (`Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor). Thus no job control in this shell.`) after I enter the password for root on the connect server (ip: 1.1.1.1).

Any suggestions? Let me know if further explanation is required. Thanks!
(My version of bash is GNU bash version 3.2.51(1))

The error message I get when removing `2>/dev/null` is:

```
Warning: no access to tty (Bad file descriptor).
Thus no job control in this shell. 
stty: standard input: Invalid argument
```

Answer (score 0):

How about passing `-s /bin/bash` to `su`?